# React Native Notification Push

Tags: reactjs, react-native, push-notification, react-redux, apple-push-notifications

I am currently working on a React Native project and trying to get familiar with React Native Push Notifications. However, i would like to use it in a particular manner. I am trying to send notifications to specific devices. As shown in the picture: [Illustration of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GTfu.png)

I took the example of a restaurant where one can send a order to the restaurant's phone and the latter can send notifications to specific devices when orders are ready.

My question is to know if there are specific ways to do so ? Or tutorials available.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a question related to react or react-native. This needs to be handled by your backend. When an order is placed you should have an APNS device token linked to a specific user that placed the order in your database. The backend then proceeds to send the relevant push notification.

So the only task device handles is retrieving device token and sending it to the server, which proceeds to send push notifications.

Here's a great library that handles all client specific procedures related to retrieving the device the device token, which I highly recommend: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification]

If you are in charge of writing the backend too, you should research the backend specific libraries that handle push notifications. Here's a good library that does so for Python/Django stack if by chance you're working with it: https://github.com/jazzband/django-push-notifications